# How can I debug my code in DNN 7 using breakpoint

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, ascx, dotnetnuke-7

I have applied some breakpoints into my Visual Studio Code and use Dot Net Nuke 7. Now I want to debug my code .So how can i debug it.

As I have created one controller page and create a page in DNN and trying to access that control as a module on that DNN page, but now the problem is I am not able to debug my code.

Comment: Are you using a Web Application Project, or are you using a "website" project with DNN itself loaded in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that instead of debugging by pressing f5, you will need to attach the debugger to the dnn process in iis.

Debug->Attach to process -> then find the W3p process that is running your dnn project.

You may need to tick Show Processes from all users to see it.

However I haven't done DNN for many years, so this is all from memory. good luck